# Get sourcecode for urls

Tags: python

I have following codes:

```
import urllib2
from itertools import product

with open('urllist.txt') as urllist:
    urls=[line.strip() for line in urllist]

for url in product(urls):
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = usock.read()
    usock.close()
    sourcecode=open('./sourcecode', 'w+')
    sourcecode.write(data)
```

When I ran it, it gave:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "12.py", line 8, in <module>
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 383, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Any idea how to fix it? Many thanks!

Comment: What did you intend to achieve by using `product`?

Comment: I would like to get sourcecode from a list of urls.

Comment: How does `url` look like?

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) returns a tuple not the item itself.:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lis = ['a','b','c']
>>> for p in product(lis):
...     print p
...     
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
```

Use a simple loop over urls:

```
for url in urls:
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have figured out another way to do it. Just change "for url in product(urls):" to "for url in urls:"

Comment: @Tom I've already mentioned that in the answer.